# JavaScript libraries for Markdown, Textile and others; Anchor references

Tags: javascript, markdown, textile

I need a javascript library to convert structured ascii text to html on the fly.
I am especially interested in the following point:

I would like do use anchored links inside pages, see http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/struct/links.html#h-12.1.1

Which library for structured text would support this or if it is not supported could be easily extended (i could write an extension)?

Can you make a suggestion for a good and simple syntax for structured ascii text for "in page links"?

```
<a href="#jumpend">jump to the end</a>
...some body text...
<a name="jumpend">this is the end</a>
```

I like the way links are written in "markdown", so how could the name anchor in a to be written extension be expressed in a nice way?

Which libraries do you know or can you recommend? Should be multi browser, good and easy to read and extend clean source code, actively maintained.

I am presently having a look at the JavaScript Markdown library "Showdown": http://attacklab.net/showdown/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you should not use markdown if you are looking for anchor references. Try the following Creole Wiki markup parsers:

- A prototype Javascript Creole 0.4 parser can be found at [MeatballSociety](http://www.meatballsociety.org/Creole/0.4/)
- [JavaScript Creole 1.0 Wiki Markup Parser](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jscreole/), based on the above

Comment: You're welcome! Good to know it helped. If this is what you were looking for, don't forget to set the answer as accepted ;)

Answer (score 3):

You might look into [markItUp!](http://markitup.jaysalvat.com/home/)

Comment: I believe that markItUp relies on the server to do the parsing.

Answer (score 0):

Textile hast a builtin "footnote" mechanism:

```
.. AJAX[1] ...

fn1. Asynchronous JavaScript and XML ..
```

As of [Textile 2.2](https://github.com/netcarver/textile) there's also a "notelist" feature: [textile.sitemonks.com/?eg=notes](http://textile.sitemonks.com/?eg=notes#results)