# What do I need to use Markdown in a Java webapp?

Tags: java, maven-2, markdown, javascript

I'm thinking on adding Markdown to a Java project using:

- Tapestry 5
- Spring
- Maven
- ( Among other technologies )

Questions:

1. What JavaScript library can I use for the client side?  I'm thinking on using Cletus' [image] [port of MarkDownSharp](http://github.com/cletus/jmd)  for the backend.
2. What strategy should I follow to add [JMD](http://github.com/cletus/jmd) to my project? My code it's a Maven project already. If JMD were available for Maven I would just create a dependency on that, but it is not.  So, should I merge it with my code base?

Comment: Just in case: [Why did you stop using Tapestry?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1303438/why-did-you-stop-using-tapestry/1310032#1310032) :) Stripes FTW!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What javascript library can I use for the client side? I'm thinking on using Cletus' port of MarkDownSharp

[ShowDown](http://attacklab.net/showdown/), [WMD](http://wmd-editor.com/) (still not open sourced) and [markItUp!](http://markitup.jaysalvat.com/home/) seem to be the most *famous* options, the later being maybe the closest to what you're looking for.

> What strategy should I follow to add JMD to my code base (it is a Maven project already). If it were available for maven I would just create a dependency on that, but In this case, Should I merge it with my code base?

Hmm... what? I'm not sure I understood the question, but I'll try. If JMD is available in a known repository, just add a dependency on it. If it isn't I would get the sources and add them to my codebase as a module (not a bid deal, there are less than 10 classes) and sync them from time to time.

#### Related questions

- [Is there any good Markdown Javascript library or control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/134235/is-there-any-good-markdown-javascript-library-or-control)
- [JavaScript libraries for Markdown, Textile and others; Anchor references](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/895135/javascript-libraries-for-markdown-textile-and-others-anchor-references)

Comment: I meant the later. JMD is not in a know repository. So, yeah, I'll  add the code into my own.  BTW I've found the javascript library used in SO: http://code.google.com/p/wmd-new/